# ScrollBar lib and React

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks, smooth-scrolling

I have built a website as one page and all section are rendered one under another. To make a smooth and nice scrolling I used the library "smooth-scrollbar". My page I build using React.
Scrolling working nice, but the issue that I have appeares when, for example I cress contact button and then it takes me to the contact form (no problem) and then my page stuck. I can scroll up and down just maybe like 100-150 px, and rest of scrolling dont work.
I have next parameters:

```
var overscrollOptions = {
  enable: true,
  effect: "glow",
  damping: 0.1,
  maxOverscroll: 150,
};

const options = {
  damping: 0.03,
  plugins: {
    overscroll: { ...overscrollOptions },
  },
};
```

```
  useEffect(() => {
    Scrollbar.use(OverscrollPlugin);
    Scrollbar.init(document.body, options);

    return () => {
      if (Scrollbar) Scrollbar.destroy(document.body);
    };
  }, []);
```

My return from App.js

```
 return (
    <div className="app">
      <Element name="home">
        <Home />
      </Element>

      <Element name="service">
        <Service />
      </Element>

      <Element name="projects">
        <Projects />
      </Element>

      <Element name="commercial">
        <Commercial />
      </Element>

      <Element name="gallery">
        <Gallery />
      </Element>

      <Element name="workprocess">
        <WorkProcess />
      </Element>

      <Element name="about">
        <About />
      </Element>

      <Element name="footer">
        <Footer />
      </Element>
    </div>
  );
```

I was trying to play with option and and I tried to go over library again and again.
Anyone maybe have some kind of idea that I could try?

Thank you!